# Query return and empty array

Tags: php, pdo

The following script:

```
<?php
try 
{
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:./path/phrases");
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM phrases');

    foreach($result as $row){
        $row['phrase'];
        $row['score'];
    }    
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

is returning:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in myscript.php on line 5
```

If I execute: Select * from phrases; in a SQL browser, I get back a long list of results, with regard to the columns phrase and score. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the ; from your query, eg $db->query('SELECT * FROM phrases');

Comment: @bumperbox No difference. How do I see what $result is for type?

Comment: Where is the function code for `getMessage()`? Or is that a built-in function?

Comment: @Fred that is part of built-in PDO exception handling mechanism.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Then it is a built-in function, thanks for the info.

Comment: yes it is. http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php

Comment: *"If I execute "Select * from phrases;" in a SQL browser, I get back a long list of results"* then why not try using double-quotes inside your query instead of singles/apostrophes?

Comment: @Fred I've updated my question. I'm not using quotes.

Comment: @Baz Ok. And removing that semi-colon from `phrases;` didn't help, from what I gather by reading your comments below.

Comment: @Baz Have a look at my 2 examples below, inside one answer. What I did not find in your code/question is that there is no mention of connecting to your DB.

Answer (score 1):

#### There are 2 examples in this answer.

The first example I found at http://juanmanuelllona.blogspot.ca/

Am providing what I hope will be a solution.

### 1)

```
try {
$db = new PDO("sqlite:./path/phrases");

echo 'database open';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM phrases";
$obj= $db->query($sql) ;

foreach ($obj as $row)
{
print('Phrase ='.$row['phrase'].' Course='.$row['score']. '&ltbr/>'); // or <br/>
}
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

### 2)

And this suggestion taken from an example at http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

```
/*** mysql hostname ***/
$hostname = 'localhost';

/*** mysql username ***/
$username = 'username';

/*** mysql password ***/
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=phrases", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database<br />';

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM phrases";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        print $row['phrase'] .' - '. $row['score'] . '<br />';
        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use echo statement:

```
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM phrases');
foreach($result as $row){
    echo $row['phrase'];
    echo $row['score'];
}
```

Comment: No output except the warning.

Comment: what do you get when you do var_dump($result); exit;  right before the foreach loop ?Also, make sure that you remove the semicolon from your original query statement.

Comment: Are you sure your PDO connection is valid? can you do var_dump($db); exit; right after you create the PDO object and see what you get ?

Comment: This returns: object(PDO)#1 (0) { }

Comment: can you do this: print_r($result->errorInfo()); and try matching the error code with what's given here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php? Look at the end of the page about error codes for SQLite.

Comment: But $result is just a bool so it wont have such a method, hence the following: Fatal error: Call to a member function errorInfo() on a non-object

Comment: Can you try this: 
try {
   $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM phrases;');
}
catch(PDOException $err)
{
    echo $err->getMessage();
}

Comment: No output, so no exception. It just returns false. Does the $db object contain any error info?

Comment: it should if its a valid PDO object.

Answer (score -1):

```
try 
{
    $db = new PDO("sqlite:./path/phrases");
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM phrases;'); // remove the Semicolon 

    foreach($result as $row){
        $row['phrase'];
        $row['score'];
    }    
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

try removing the Semicolon inside the statement.

Comment: Still gives the same warning